# How to play different sounds in different buttons in tableview

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview

I want to play different sounds when i tap different buttons in my tableview cells. Right now every button plays the same audio file when i tap them. How can i tell my app to play different audio files when i tap different buttons.

HERE IS MY CODE

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController6: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {


    var player = AVQueuePlayer()



    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

    //Array of Rifles

    var arrayOfRifles = ["AK47", "AUGA1", "FAMAS", "G36K", "K1A", "K2", "M4A1", "M4Silencer", "M16", "M60", "MicroGALIL", "QBZ95", "RPK", "ScarHeavy", "Scarlight", "SG552", "TAR21", "Tommy", "Type89", "XM8"]
    var buttonDataRifles = ["AK47", "AUGA1", "FAMAS", "G36K", "K1A", "K2", "M4A1", "M4Silencer", "M16", "M60", "MicroGALIL", "QBZ95", "RPK", "ScarHeavy", "Scarlight", "SG552", "TAR21", "Tommy", "Type89", "XM8"]
    var soundArrayRifles = ["AK47", "AUGA1", "FAMAS", "G36K", "K1A", "K2", "M4A1", "M4Silencer", "M16", "M60", "MicroGALIL", "QBZ95", "RPK", "ScarHeavy", "Scarlight", "SG552", "TAR21", "Tommy", "Type89", "XM8"]

    var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


//Functions for tableView

    //Cell - For Rifles

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return (arrayOfRifles.count)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell6 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell6", for: indexPath) as! ViewControllerTableViewCell6

        cell6.myImage.image = UIImage(named: arrayOfRifles[indexPath.row] + ".jpg")
        cell6.myButton.setTitle(buttonDataRifles[indexPath.row], for: UIControlState.normal)
        cell6.myButton.tag = indexPath.row
        cell6.myButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
        return cell6
        }


    @IBAction func buttonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {

        if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "AK47", withExtension: "mp3") {
            player.removeAllItems()
            player.insert(AVPlayerItem(url: url), after: nil)
            player.play()

            }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: soundArrayRifles[sender.tag], withExtension: "mp3") {
        player.removeAllItems()
        player.insert(AVPlayerItem(url: url), after: nil)
        player.play()

        }
```

Try this. This should fix it.